# If $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic and $C^{k}$, $\hat{f}(n)=O\left(\frac{1}{|n|^{k}}\right)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

My question is:

Suppose that $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic, and $C^{k}$. Show that $\hat{f}(n)=O\left(\frac{1}{|n|^{k}}\right)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. This notation means that there is a constant $C$ such $|\hat{f}(n)|\leq C/|n|^{k}$.

My attempt:

Using the complex notation, 
$$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$

Using integration by parts, I can see that

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx=-\sum_{j=i}^{k}\left.\frac{1}{i^{j}n^{j}}f^{(j-1)}(x)e^{-inx}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{(k)}(x)e^{-inx}dx $$

First, $f^{(k)}$ is continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$, so the integral  on the right side exists. By the equation above,

\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx\right|\leq|\sum_{j=i}^{k}\left|\left.\frac{1}{i^{j}n^{j}}f^{(j-1)}(x)e^{-inx}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\right|+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f^{(k)}(x)e^{-inx}\right|dx
\tag{1}
\label{1}
\end{equation}

There is a constant $A>0$ such that 
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f^{(k)}(x)e^{-inx}\right|dx\leq A\cdot 2\pi,$$
and we have

\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx\right|\leq\sum_{j=i}^{k}\left|\left.\frac{1}{i^{j}n^{j}}f^{(j-1)}(x)e^{-inx}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\right|+\frac{A}{2\pi}
\tag{2}
\label{2}
\end{equation}

Now, let

$$M=\frac{1}{2\pi}\max_{1\leq j\leq k} \left|\left.\frac{f^{(j-1)}(x)e^{-inx}}{i^{j}}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\right|.$$

By $\ref{2}$, we have

\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx\right|\leq M \sum_{j=i}^{k}\frac{1}{|n|^{j}}+\frac{A}{2\pi}
\tag{3}
\label{3}
\end{equation}

So, replacing, we got by $\ref{3}$,

\begin{equation}
\left|\hat{f}(n)\right|\leq 2\pi M \sum_{j=i}^{k}\frac{1}{|n|^{j}}+A
\end{equation}

I think I'm close to prove that there is a constant $B$ such that

\begin{equation}
|n|^{k}\hat{f}(n)\leq B
\tag{4}
\label{4}
\end{equation}

Did I work right till here? If yes, what can I do to finish my problem?

Comment: What is $\hat{f'}_n$ if you know $\hat{f}_n$?

Comment: @Cbjork $\hat{f'}(n)=in\hat{f}(n)$. How can this help me?

Comment: Isn't this just straight integration by parts? \begin{align} \hat{f} &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f e^{-inx} dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f' e^{-inx} dx \quad \text{(extra term disappears as $f$ periodic implies $f'$ periodic)} \\ &= \dots \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{(in)^{k}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^{(k)} e^{-inx} dx \\ \implies |\hat{f}| &= \bigg| \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{(in)^{k}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^{(k)} e^{-inx} dx \bigg| \\ &\le \frac{1}{|n|^{k}} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{2 \pi}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f^{(k)}| dx}_{C} \end{align}

Comment: @Mattos, could you write as an answer? You are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that if $h$ is a periodic function over $[-\pi, \pi)$, then

\begin{align}
h(x)e^{-inx} \lvert_{-\pi}^{\pi} &= h(\pi)e^{-in \pi} - h(- \pi)e^{in \pi} \\
&= h(\pi)e^{-in \pi} - h(\pi)e^{in \pi} \\
&= -2i h(\pi) \left[ \frac{e^{in \pi} - e^{-in \pi}}{2i} \right] \\
&= -2i h(\pi) \sin(n \pi) \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Hence, integrating by parts $k$ times and using the fact that [if $f$ is periodic with period $\alpha$, then $f'$ is periodic with period $\alpha$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Periodic_Function), we have

\begin{align} 
\hat{f} &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f e^{-inx} dx \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left[ \require{cancel} \cancel{\frac{f e^{-inx}}{-in} \bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}} + \frac{1}{in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f' e^{-inx} dx \right] \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f' e^{-inx} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{in} \left[ \require{cancel} \cancel{\frac{f' e^{-inx}}{-in} \bigg|_{-\pi}^{\pi}} + \frac{1}{in} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f'' e^{-inx} dx \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{(in)^{2}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f' e^{-inx} dx \\
&= \dots \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{(in)^{k}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^{(k)} e^{-inx} dx \\
\implies |\hat{f}| &= \bigg| \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{(in)^{k}} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^{(k)} e^{-inx} dx \bigg| \\ 
&\le \frac{1}{n^{k}} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{2 \pi}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f^{(k)}| dx}_{C} 
\end{align}

Therefore, we have $\hat{f} = \mathcal{O}(n^{-k})$.