# Using Fourier Series show convergence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Fourier sine series:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{∞}s_n(f)\sin(nπx), \;\:\, s_n(f) = 2 \int_{0}^{1}\sin(nπx)f(x)dx,$$
Fourier cosine series:
$$ f(x) = \frac{c_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{∞}c_n(f)\cos(nπx), \;\:\, c_n(f) = 2\int_{0}^{1}\cos(nπx)f(x)dx. $$
For given $k ∈ \mathbb{N_0}$, show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{∞} n^k|c_n(f)| < ∞, \;\:\,
\sum_{n=1}^{∞}n^k|s_n(f)| < ∞ $$
if $f ∈ C^{k+1}([0, 1],  \mathbb{C})$ with $f^{(2j)}(0) = f^{(2j)}(1) = 0$ for $0 ≤ j ≤ k/2$ for the case of $s_n(f)$ and $f^{(2j+1)}(0) = f^{(2j+1)}(1) = 0$ for $0 ≤ j < k/2$ for the case of $c_n(f)$.

**My Approach:**

$$ c_n(f') = 2\int_{0}^{1} \cos(n\pi x)f'(x)dx = 2[\cos(nx\pi)f(x)]_{0}^{1} - 2\int_{0}^{1} \cos'(n\pi x)f(x)dx = 2[\cos(n\pi)f(1)-f(0)] + n\pi\int_{0}^{1} \sin(nx\pi)f(x)dx = 2((-1)^nf(1)-f(0)) + n\pi s_n(f).  $$

Furthermore

$$  s_n(f') = 2\int_{0}^{1} \sin(n\pi x)f'(x)dx = 2[\sin(nx\pi)f(x)]_{0}^{1} - 2\int_{0}^{1} \sin'(n\pi x)f(x)dx = 2[-n\pi\int_{0}^{1}cos(n\pi x)f(x)dx = -n\pi c_n(f) $$

**My Question:**

Am I on the right way to a solution? And is it possible that that should be it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If my approach is correct and what else should I do or this is the end of the proof?

Comment: I don't know where you are trying to go with your approach. You would be better off _explaining_ what you are trying to do in your post _before_ you do any working. I would use a very similar approach to what I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2936113/if-f-is-2-pi-periodic-and-ck-hatfn-o-left-frac1nk-righ/2937539#2937539) and just integrate by parts directly on the integrals for $s_{n}(f), c_{n}(f)$, from which you should find $s_{n}, c_{n} \sim C n^{-(k+1)}$. Are you sure the term in the summation is $n^{k}$?